# Mobile browsers freezing on jQuery prompt

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iphone, google-chrome

I want users to be able to enter their own options to a few selects when selecting "add new". I am using the following code from a SO answer, can't remember where, which works:

```
$(function(){
$('select').change( function(){
    var value = $(this).val();
    if (value == 'new') {
        var other = prompt('Add new:');
        if(!other) return false;
        $(this).append('<option value"'
            + other
            + '" selected="selected">'
            + other
            + '</option>');
    }
});
});
```

However, when i try to "add option" from certain mobile devices, iphones so far, the browser displays the prompt but freezes completely, forcing a restart of the browser. This occurs in chrome but not safari.
Are there other ways of prompting text input or am i doing something wrong? I am not very experienced with jQuery.

I am using jQuery 1.11.3 from the google CDN.

[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y5hwxr28/) gives me the same result of it working perfectly on pc and in mobile safari, but not on mobile google chrome. I tried it with an iphone 5.

Comment: JSFIDDLE could be apprieciated

Comment: @JqueryKing I added a jsfiddle, it acts the same way my website does, see description.